# How to grab all comments from all posts i ever had from a facebook page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-comments

i'm trying to build a Facebook application that pulls all time comments from a specific Facebook page and fill it into a excel sheet.

i am using PHP SDK V4.0, and what i found is the following:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/{post-id}/comments');
```

but what i need is to pull all comments from all posts i ever had, something similar to:

```
$_request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/*/comments');
```

hope that someone have a solution
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is by reading all posts with `/page-id/posts` and making a separate call to `/post-id/comments`, there is no way to get all comments in one call.

Also, keep in mind that you will not get all of them per post, you may need to implement [paging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging).